# capture buttons values on submission

Tags: php, jquery

```
     <form method="post">
            <button name="Day1" value="16">
            <button name="Day2" value="32">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
     </form>
```

I have some javascript that toggles the values of each button based on number of clicks

how do i catch values to submit as POST for backend handling

Regards,
H

Comment: `alert($('.Day1').attr('value'));` and its better to have id's that are all lower cased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of incrementing the button values, increment the values of hidden inputs related to each button.

```
 <form method="post">
    <button type="button" onclick="this.nextElementSibling.value++;">Day1</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="Day1" value="0">

    <button type="button" onclick="this.nextElementSibling.value++;">Day2</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="Day2" value="0">

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
```

This way they can easily be submitted with your form.